# Understanding Sinon clock `tick` vs `tickAsync`

Tags: javascript, jestjs, sinon, clock

I am trying to understand the difference between `clock.tick` and `clock.tickAsync` and where should I use each one. The explanation in the docs is not clear to me, and by looking at the code itself I still can't understand where and when should I use each method. Can anyone help me with a concrete code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The tickAsync() will also break the event loop, allowing any scheduled promise callbacks to execute before running the timers.

First, I recommend looking the [video about event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0).

If short, the difference between `tick` and `tickAsync` is that `tick` - is call timers **synchronous** and `tickAsync` is - call timers **asynchronous** that allow to execute resolved promises before calling timers

What synchronous means. Let's look at the example code which we would test

```
function myFunction() {
  setTimeout(() => console.log('foo'), 1000)
  Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('zoo'));
  console.log('bar')
}
```

and our synchronous test code

```
it('should test synchronously', () => {
   myFunction()
   tick(1000); // This would call scheduled timers synchronously ⚠️
   console.log('baz')
});
// print 'bar'
// print 'foo'
// print 'baz'
// print 'zoo'
```

and now let's see the same test code but with `tickAsync`

```
it('should test synchronously', () => {
   myFunction()
   tickAsync(1000);
   console.log('baz')
});
// print 'bar'
// print 'baz' 
// print 'zoo' 
// print 'foo'
```

As you can see, the order of printed string is changed.
Now the same code but with `await`

```
it('should test synchronously', async () => {
   myFunction()
   await tickAsync(1000);
   console.log('baz')
});
// print 'bar'
// print 'zoo' 
// print 'foo' 
// print 'baz'
```

To understand why the order changed, you should understand the difference betweens [micro tasks queue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide) and regular queue. But if you watched the video from link above, you already should get the idea

P.S.
Also, you should understand that `sinon.useFakeTimers();` will replace `setTimeout` and `setInterval` on own implementation that allow sinon to have full control over your timers passed to these functions

This is a **very rough approximation** how sinon `tick` & `tickAsync` implemented

```
scheduledTimers = [];

function useFakeTimers() {
    global.setInterval = global.setTimeout = (fn) => {
        scheduledTimers.push(fn);
    }
}

function tick() {
    while (scheduledTimers.length) {
        scheduledTimers.shift()();
    }
}

function tickAsync() {
    // Call timers on the next tick
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => tick());
}
```

Comment: so is it safe to say that the most common and safest usage of ticking methods would be `tickAsync`? I guess that most of the time when you advance the time in your tests, you expect all timers (to that point) to be settled before you continue to your next expectation, right?

Comment: It depends, I personally prefer tick whenever it’s possible just not to deal with asynchronous tests. But yes tickAsync behave closely to real world and allow to handle such complex cases like mix timers and promises

Answer (score 0):

Due to inability to edit @maksimr's answer (too many pending edits), following is the explanation for why the order is as it is

***Note**: Watching minutes 23 to 28 of the aforementioned talk would be beneficial for grasping the difference between `task queues` and `microtasks`*

##### Synchronous Timer (`tick`)

- `myFunction()` is called:

  - `setTimeout(...)`: schedules `foo` onto the **Tasks** queue for after 1000ms.
  - `Promise.resolve().then(...)`: schedules 'zoo' onto the **Microtasks** queue.
  - `console.log('bar')` 1️⃣: executes immediately.
  - Move back to the main function.
- `tick(1000)`: Move forward till the timer is over [sync timer advancement].

  - `console.log('foo')` 2️⃣: timer is triggered immediately [timers that are over due to the ticks in the **Tasks** queue are emptied **synchronously**]
- `console.log('baz')` 3️⃣: main function continues.
- `console.log('zoo')` 4️⃣: promise callback executes last [**Microtasks** queue is emptied].
- **Order of output:** 'bar', 'foo', 'baz', 'zoo'.

##### Asynchronous Timer without Await (`tickAsync`)

- `myFunction()` is called (same as above including 1️⃣).
- `tickAsync(1000)`: schedules the timer's callback after pending async operations, thus ticking the clock won't trigger the timer now, but rather set the scheduled timers to run async [e.g. deferred for later after the **microtasks**].
- `console.log('baz')` 2️⃣: main function continues.
- `console.log('zoo')` 3️⃣: Promise callbacks execute [**microtasks** finish].
- `console.log('foo')` 4️⃣: Timer's callback executes [**tasks** finish] .
- **Order of output:** 'bar', 'baz', 'zoo', 'foo' .

##### Asynchronous Timer with Await (`await tickAsync`)

- `myFunction()` is called (same as above including 1️⃣).
- `await tickAsync(1000)`: waits for all async operations, **microtasks** then **tasks**.
- `console.log('zoo')` 2️⃣: Promise callbacks execute [**microtasks** finish].
- `console.log('foo')` 3️⃣: Timer's callback executes [**tasks** finish] .
- `console.log('baz')` 4️⃣: executes after awaiting `tickAsync`.
- **Order of output:** 'bar', 'zoo',  'foo',  'baz'.

I'm coming to think of `tickAsync` as getting the timers executed asynchronously in a late manner, after promises (very asynchronously), and adding the `await` flag enforces this asynchronicity to get executed immediately while preserving the order of resolving the promises first.